# Datetime and convert function

Tags: python, datetime, time

I'm really trying so hard to findout what's wrong with my code here. So here's the question:

Writing the function convert_datetime:

Convert a datetime string in "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS" format to a datetime object.
Return the datetime object.

This is my code:

```py
def convert_datetime(datetime_str):
    datetime.strptime(datetime_str, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS")
```

[And this is the error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZFtw.jpg)

Can anyone please help me? I spend days on this problem

Comment: In Python, [indentation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp) is critically important.

Comment: Please post code, input/output, and errors as plain text.  Images are hard to work with, for many good reasons.

Comment: You're looking to convert and ISO8601 formatted string into a datetime object - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/127803/10197418). If you're looking for parsing directives for `strptime`, see the datetime module [docs section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

Answer (score 0):

Pls use `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` instead of `"yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS"`.

Test Code:

```
from datetime import datetime

def convert_datetime(datetime_str):
    return datetime.strptime(datetime_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

datetime_str = "2023-11-21 20:00:00"
result = convert_datetime(datetime_str)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
2023-11-21 20:00:00
```